# Joomla limitations

Tags: php, joomla

This is my first time using Joomla, I need to create a website with basic functions such as about us, products, login, contactus with captcha and shopping cart (but it wont be linked to a payment gateway, it will only send a mail to a client with items of interest), are those things doable in Joomla, or is it better to code PHP directly ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to achieve all these features with Joomla combined with VirtueMart and other plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I have a design, how can I use it in joomla ?

Comment: Read about Joomla Themes - it should put you in the right direction.

Comment: I would not use virtue mart for this, I would use something simple and easy like rokquickcart. Virtue mart is total overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can accomplish all the requirements with Joomla. I have been doing Joomla for a long time now.

According to my knowledge, the best plugin which can get the work done for you is [**VirtueMart**](http://virtuemart.net/).

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful, may I ask, since you are experienced with joomla, can you just place php code inside joomla pages, or it has to be defined as components, I mean simple functions or form validation ? also how to start, I have good experience in php but very limited to joomla, how can I start, thanks in advance

Comment: Joomla builds in form validation.
How big of an item list are you talking about? Virtue mart is very complex and has a steep learning curve. If you aren't offering coupons or needing to do shipping or calculate taxes I would go with a simpler solution.

When you say how to start are you talking about how to start coding or how to start using? You shouldn't really need to do much coding with the proper use of extensions and core.

Comment: Thanks Elin, well, I have a static html website that my client wants to be implemented on joomla, but he wants to integrate login, mailing lists and a shoppingcart that only submits to an email not to a payment gateway, I have no clue how to do this using joomla :)

Comment: Really not hard.  Do the install with brochure sample data to start i you haven't yet, add a mailing list extension from the JED (I  use one that integrates with mailchimp), and  ... if you explain exactly what you want in the email and how large the product list is I could probably suggest something but seriously keep it simple and use the core.

Comment: the cart will only contain a couple of items not that big, this should be submitted in an email. Also what is the best way to turn my site into joomla, customise a joomla template, or there is someway to import the existing html and css into a joomla template ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is perfect for the requirements you outline but some points are worth noting:

1. Joomla is already a powerful and complete CMS solution. you shouldn't necessarily need to custom code to achieve what you want.
2. Virtuemart is a complex and arguably cumbersome ecommerce add-on ("components" in Joomla lingo). There are simpler add-ons which may suit your purposes much better with a more relaxed learning curve. "J2 Store" comes to mind. Here's a good place to start: http://extensions.joomla.org/category/e-commerce
3. If you already have a design and want to convert this for use in Joomla you need to consider factors such as whether it's important that your site is responsive and if different section will require unique styles or layouts. If you have have a budget for your project you can even pay to have your design converted into a Joomla template leaving you to install it in a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

With VirtueMart (my favorite) and K2 Store you can do all you ask for.

You can't import html and css, because joomla templates have difrerent structure.

To costumize your template i recomand to use default Joomla template (now for 2.5 are more extensions aviabile than 3.0).
If you don't know where to start, take a look at template positions, and try to change the css according to your design/layout.
A joomla template must have:

```
       mynewtemplate/ 
          css/
              template.css 
          images/
          index.php
          templateDetails.xml
```